# honoring quotes in a remote ssh execution with SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to execute a remote script with spaces in parameters and ssh is messing with them.

I got this script in a machine

```
#!/bin/bash

CONT="1"
while test "$#" -gt 0
do
    echo "P${CONT} [$1]"
    P="$P P${CONT} [$1]"
    shift
    let "CONT++"
done
echo "DEBUG: `date` - SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND [$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND]"
```

and produces this output:

```
./test_ssh.sh a 'b c' d
P1 [a]
P2 [b c]
P3 [d]
DEBUG: dj abr 19 14:03:52 CEST 2018 - SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND []
```

from a remote machine I get this output:

```
ssh root@olivera "test_ssh.sh a 'b c' d"
P1 [a]
P2 ['b]
P3 [c']
P4 [d]
DEBUG: dj abr 19 14:05:04 CEST 2018 - SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND [test_ssh.sh a 'b c' d]
```

I've tried several combinations with double quotes and scapes whithout any success.

any hints?

Comment: It works for me bash-to-bash. I've pasted exactly your code. What login shells do you use? What versions?

Comment: /bin/bash in both sides. could it be ssh is forcing another shell?

Comment: Are you using `ForceCommand` in `sshd_config` or `command=` in `authorized_keys` (for the key used)? According to the doc _and_ code, those are the only cases that should set envvar `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` . If you are using one of those, is it set to the correct file?

Comment: yes, I'm using command= to restrict what can be executed remotely.

Comment: @muzzol Until you have updated your question to include what's in that command it will be impossible to answer.